# Tags in AWS with Bitbucket YAML files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tags, bitbucket

I work with bitbucket and AWS and I am trying to add tags to multiple resources in cloud formations templates for example if we have 30 S3 resources in a cloud formation template and I want to add the Tag "Car: BMW" to all of them is there any way to do this? I've used resource tag editor in AWS but I need to do it trough the yaml file in bitbucket. I have been searching but can't find a answer.

I know that adding Tags, key and value works but I want to find out if it exist a smarter way to do this. For example if I add tags to a s3 bucket in a yaml file I can just write in:

Tags:

- Key: Car
- Value: BMW

But I want to find out how to do it to all the resources in a YAML file instead of adding that 3 lines of code to all the resources which is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tags to all your resources within a CloudFormation Stack by applying the tag on the Stack level.

Go to CloudFormation > Select your Stack > Action > Create changeset for the current stack.

On Step 3, you can apply new tags to all the resources defined within the Stack.
[image]

If you want to script it out using a yaml of tags, you can use the cli command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-change-set.html